# Get the value of password confirmation field register

Tags: 8, forms

I want to use the default register form to get the value of the password confirmation field on register. If a user change his password it will call my API ans send the new information.

I can't find the ID of this field.

**EDIT**: I find the solution with

**$confirm_pass = $form_state->getUserInput()['pass']['pass2'];**

```php
function alter_form_form_alter(&$form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id)
{
    if ($form_id == 'user_form') {
        $form['#validate'] = ['update_validate'];
    }
}

function update_validate(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $tab = array())
{
  $values = $form_state->getValues();
  $password_conf = $values['#ID#'];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Sorry you got downvoted. But unfortunately it's unclear what exactly you are asking for as you forgot to provide more context on what exactly you are trying to achieve; and in what file and function you are currently working. Please update your question for clarification; to share a detailed and reproducible problem. Many thanks :)

Comment: @leymannx thank you I did a better one

Comment: Sending unencrypted passwords to an external API?!

Comment: no! I send crypted data on a token!